# C# Service using Sockets & Threading With PHP Web Interface (PHP sockets)

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, communication

Hi Hope someone can help me.

- My .net app that connects (via tcp)
  to a service we shall call
  "super-service" (reads and sends data)
- My app has an open socket for PHP to
  connect to (To allow people from a web interface to connect to "super-service" using their username and passwords)
- When someone connects via PHP i want
  to spawn a thread (which is a new
  connection to super-service)

I originally thought of doing it so the thread that handles the PHP connection is the same thread that connects to "super-service" which would make life very simple.

But PHP will close the socket once the page has loaded and i need to maintain a connection to "super-service" still for that user of the web interface.

So I thought of doing it the following way:

- 1) PHP Connects to an open socket on
  my app and sends username / password
- 2) My app spawns a new thread that
  connects to "super-service" (using
  username / pass supplied) and creates
  a new Guid
- 3) That spawned thread then get put
  into a Dictionary(Guid, Thread) and
  reports the Guid back to PHP to be
  saved in a session.
- 4) PHP connects again to my app but
  with a GUID and a message.
- 5) my app finds the thead associated
  to that user/client (using the guid)

Upto there i can do.

But the next steps of being able to send and get info to/from that thead (which then sends/gets to super-service)is where i'm stuck...

Alternatively is there a better way?

Thanks again in advance!

NOTE: question rewritten to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: Is the thread still doing work after the socket to the PHP app is closed the first time?

Comment: Yeah the thread needs to maintain a tcp connection to "super-service"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really send a message to a thread, but you *can* store a message that another thread may pick up. If you want to go that way, have a look at `Monitor.Wait()` and `Monitor.PulseAll()`. You'd have to store data somewhere the target thread can access it, and have the target threads wait and check for new messages.

Alternatively you could just store the sockets that are connected to the "super service" in that dictionary instead of trying to control the threads.

Comment: Hi I've edited my question to hopefully make more sense!

I think i wasn't clear enough that i want to be able to make multiple connections to the service (e.g. multiple logins to the service via my app from diffrent people via a web interface)

Comment: hey thanks for the advice. I like the idea of just storing the sockets iv been working on both approaches to see what fits best. thanks for the help.